# real time data class in Java

Tags: java

Is there a class in java for getting Real time data from a process?

E.g. in Excel we use `=RTD(RealTimeServerProgID,ServerName,Topic1,[Topic2], ...)`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RealTimeData uses COM. You would have to use Java-COM bridge, for instance [j-interop](http://www.j-interop.org/sampleusage.html) and attempt to talk with the service that implements [IRTDServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.irtdserver%28v=office.11%29.aspx). You probably have to use dcomcnfg to find the correct COM service to connect to.

Comment: thanks, could you provide me a example, since my new to JAVA-COM bridge